# UI and api access authentication issue in openshift

Tags: python, java, angular, nginx, openshift

I have my froent end in angular which calls different apis (python and java) for getting data. It renders content via ngnix.  All are running in seprate pods in openshift.Frontend route is protected via sso which is fine. But, backend api routes  are also protected which is creating problems accessing via ui resulting in 302 errors. What is the best way to fix this? I want my ui to seemlessly access the backend apis and display it on browser?